# Join/concatenate three fields in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, string-concatenation

```
varchar(10) fld1
varchar(15) fld2 
varchar(20) fld3
```

are stored in T1

MS SQL:

```
select fld1 + '/' + fld2 + '/' + fld3 as fldTest 
from T
```

Output: `fld1/fld2/fld3`

If i type this in PL/SQL, 
the above is not working

How can i output `fld1/fld2/fld3` using PL/SQL?

Comment: Use `CONCAT` function

Answer (score 1):

SQL uses `||` for string concatenation and Oracle complies with the SQL standard:

```
select fld1 || '/' || fld2 || '/' || fld3 as fldTest 
from T
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the string concatenation operator from '+' to `||`:

```
select fld1 || '/' || fld2 || '/' || fld3 as fldTest 
from T
```

[`+` is supported in sql server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx), while [Oracle uses `||`.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the + with ||. Concatination in PLSQL is the ||. i.e. select fld1 || '/' + fld2 || '/' || fld3 as fldTest from T